# Create a circle that fills up the remaining space in a flexbox cell

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a 2-cell flexbox with a fixed-height (mobile screen), and one cell stacked on top of the other. I need all of the content of the top-cell to be displayed.. the bottom-cell should yield as much space as possible to allow this. This part was easy.

```css
.main-container {
  height: 400px;
  width: 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.content-container {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 0;
    background-color: green;
}

.content {
  height: 100px;
}

.remaining-space {
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="content-container">
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="remaining-space"></div>
</div>
```

... with that the `content-container` will grow as needed (in this example it's 100px) and the rest is taken up by the remaining-space cell.

What I need to do is fill the `remaining-space` cell with a **circle** that is as big as it can be, but doesn't force the `remaining-space` cell to grow in height/width... and I need to do it with just html/css.

The only way I've seen to enforce a 1:1 ratio (square/circle) is by using the padding-bottom trick where the padding is calculated using the element's width. This doesn't work for me because `remaining-space` cell might have a larger width than it's height.. which will cause the cell to grow in height. This is especially difficult in that the container is responsive so the actual width in pixels is never known.

Comment: are you open to using an SVG circle as a background image? Because then you can just use the `background-size:contain` property without having to over-engineer anything.

Comment: What is the purpose of the circle?

Comment: show a screen of the desired result, pls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple gradient can do it:

```css
.main-container {
  height: 400px;
  width: 200px;
  display: inline-flex;
  vertical-align: top;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.content-container {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  background-color: green;
}

.content {
  height: 100px;
}

.remaining-space {
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  height: 100%;
  background: 
    radial-gradient(circle closest-side, red 98%, transparent) 
    lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="content-container">
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="remaining-space"></div>
</div>

<div class="main-container" style="height:200px;">
  <div class="content-container">
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="remaining-space"></div>
</div>
```

Clip-path can also do it:

```css
.main-container {
  height: 400px;
  width: 200px;
  display: inline-flex;
  vertical-align: top;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.content-container {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  background-color: green;
}

.content {
  height: 100px;
}

.remaining-space {
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  height: 100%;
  background: lightgrey;
}

.remaining-space>div {
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
  clip-path: circle(closest-side)
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="content-container">
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="remaining-space">
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="main-container" style="height:200px;">
  <div class="content-container">
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="remaining-space">
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Where you can also have content inside

```css
.main-container {
  height: 400px;
  width: 200px;
  display: inline-flex;
  vertical-align: top;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.content-container {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  background-color: green;
}

.content {
  height: 100px;
}

.remaining-space {
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  height: 100%;
  background: lightgrey;
}

.remaining-space>div {
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
  clip-path: circle(closest-side);
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  font-size:30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="content-container">
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="remaining-space">
    <div> text </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="main-container" style="height:200px;">
  <div class="content-container">
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="remaining-space">
    <div> text </div>
  </div>
</div>
```